# ASPX page got entirely replaced by AjaxControlToolkit combined script

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I got this weird problem, I have an ASPX page that include AjaxControlToolkit ScriptManager, and the aspx file looks to have no problem . But when I am trying to access this particular page from browser, it prompt me to download the page, and what's inside is something like this:

```
//START AjaxControlToolkit.Compat.Timer.Timer.js
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Sys.Timer = function() {
Sys.Timer.initializeBase(this);this._interval = 1000;this._enabled = false;this._timer = null;}
Sys.Timer.prototype = {
get_interval: function() {
return this._interval;},
set_interval: function(value) {
if (this._interval !== value) {
this._interval = value;this.raisePropertyChanged('interval');if (!this.get_isUpdating() && (this._timer !== null)) {
this._stopTimer();this._startTimer();}
}
...
...
```

I have no idea what is going on here. It is a .Net 3.5 Web Application, other than this page everything is working fine.

Code Snippet:

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager runat="Server" ID="ScriptManager1" />

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        //...
    </script>

    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="hiddenTargetControlForModalPopup" Style="display: none" />
    <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender runat="server" ID="proModalPopup" BehaviorID="proModalPopupBehavior"
        TargetControlID="hiddenTargetControlForModalPopup" PopupControlID="proPopup"
        BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" DropShadow="True" PopupDragHandleControlID="proPopupDragHandle"
        CancelControlID="OkButton" X="200" Y="200" RepositionMode="RepositionOnWindowScroll">
    </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
```

Comment: What to do mean by AjaxControlToolkit manager ?

Comment: Can you please post the code snippet of your aspx page? It seems there's some problem there, which prompts you to download it.

Comment: @GuruKara I mean the ToolkitScriptManager

Comment: @Daredev I've updated the question with the snippet, it is quite a simple code.

Comment: I suspect you have a JavaScript error in same place, like a missing ; or missing closing braces.

Comment: @GuruKara I've done a scan on the javascript and did notice there's a ; missing, but I'm restricted to modified the problem file, will update the result once it is done.

Comment: @GuruKara corrected javascript in the ASPX form doesn't help, it still prompting me to download the file.

Comment: In situations like these I suggest you to reconstruct the whole page again from scratch adding one control after other one by one to pin point the problem area.

Comment: @GuruKara I have no liberty to do that, I can only investigate and correct the problem, now there's another form having same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just learnt that the web page is going through Application Request Routing (ARR) and rebooting the ARR solve the issue, suspecting the cache on ARR is to blamed.